# git prompt not working in Android Studio terminal

Tags: git, ubuntu, android-studio

I've configured `git-prompt.sh` in ubuntu terminal successfully.
Previously it was working fine in both Android Studio &  ubuntu terminal but suddenly it is not working in Android Studio terminal

- tried deleting Android Studio configuration.

[image: Android Studio terminal & gnome-terminal]

my `.bashrc` sample

```
# Enable tab completion
source /home/rnztx/git/git_wiki/git-completion.bash

# colors!
cyan="\[\033[0;36m\]"
cyanD="\[\033[1;36m\]"
green="\[\033[0;32m\]"
greenD="\[\033[1;32m\]"
redD="\[\033[1;31m\]"
red="\[\033[0;31m\]"
blue="\[\033[0;34m\]"
blueD="\[\033[1;34m\]"
purple="\[\033[0;35m\]"
purpleD="\[\033[1;35m\]"
reset="\[\033[0m\]"
# Change command prompt

source /home/rnztx/git/git_wiki/git-prompt.sh

export GIT_PS1_SHOWDIRTYSTATE=1
# '\u' adds the name of the current user to the prompt
# '\$(__git_ps1)' adds git-related stuff
# '\W' adds the name of the current directory

export PS1="$purple\u@\h:$green\$(__git_ps1)$green\W$ $reset"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like something messed up with my `/etc/bash.bashrc`
so, now I've replaced `/etc/bash.bashrc` with my users `.bashrc` file.

> Make sure you backup your `/etc/bash.bashrc` profile